# Extract value from vector to another

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, spatial-join, extract

I have two vector (shapefile) data. One contains soil order for county, and the other one contains boundary for each county. I want to extract the soil order for each county by using county boundary. But I am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

To provide the response based on [@artwork21 comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299754/extract-value-from-vector-to-another#comment482455_299754).

To identify areas in one shapefile that contain the areas in a different shapefile as related to your soils data. You can than extract the data in your attribute table using a Spatial Join feature. Here is a tutorial using QGIS that you can reference [Performing Spatial Joins](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)

I've included a few of the general steps with some visuals for reference. You will need to input the datasets you have in each of the corresponding inputs of the spatial join tools and methodology.

Go to Layer ‣ Add Vector Layer. Browse

[image]

Go to Vector ‣ Data Management Tools ‣ Join attributes by location.

[image]